Why the id of a list in spring boot list be null when creating in it in a parent entity?
I have a problem in Order Item order_id its null because I create OrderItems inside order like this the JSON for order
{
 "supplier": {
    "supplierId": 1,
    "supplierName": "yahya",
    "country": "Algeria",
    "region": "undefined",
    "productIds": [142, 141]
  },
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "order_price": 10
    },
    {
      "productId": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "order_price": 15
    }
  ],
  "orderType": "IMPORT",
  "orderDate": "2024-05-10",
  "reference": "ABC123",
  "total_price": 35
}

package com.example.importexportservice.models;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_item")
public class OrderItem {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_item_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;
    @Column(name = "Order_price")
    private int Order_price;

    public OrderItem() {
    }


    public OrderItem(Long id, Order order, Long productId, int quantity, int order_price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.order = order;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.Order_price = order_price;
    }


} 

package com.example.importexportservice.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_table")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }

    public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_Type")
    private OrderType orderType;

    public Order(Long orderId, Supplier supplier, List<OrderItem> orderItems, OrderType orderType, Date orderDate, String reference, int total_price) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.orderItems= orderItems;
        this.orderType = orderType;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.reference = reference;
        Total_price = total_price;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "order_date")
    private Date orderDate;




    @Column(name = "order_reference")
    private String reference;

    @Column(name = "order_Total_price")
    private int Total_price;

    public Order() {
    }


}

So I found order id in orderitem null  even I tried to loop the list in the constructeur and affect the order id but still I found it null. Do I have the mapping wrong or can I do something else?

What method did you use to found order id? Did you look in database table? Id created when record is written to database, GenerationType.IDENTITY implemented there

In multiple ways we can solve this problem. Here I'm explaining 1 of them.
You have to make changes in both Order and OrderItem POJO classes.
Remove  private Order order; from OrderItem and in Order just replace your @OneToMany annotation with
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id")

also you can refer this Gist
